# Is there a way I can remove this new dataframe from the larger dataframe?

Tags: r

Please I need some assistance on how to resolve this. I have a dataframe (myData) with over 57,000 rows and 129 columns and my response variable is a factor of 3-levels. My intention was to reduce the size of one of the instant classes in my response variable by 80% but when I used this code, it instead created a subset, "reduced" from the myData dataframe as against my intention of dropping the rows. How can I subtract this subset from the main dataframe or is there another way I could have done it?

```
 reduced <- myData %>% filter(marker == "Natural") %>% dplyr::slice_sample(prop = 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `reduced` data with `unreduced` data i.e `marker` without `"Natural"`.

```
library(dplyr)

reduced <- myData %>% 
               filter(marker == "Natural") %>% 
               dplyr::slice_sample(prop = 0.8)

unreduced <- myData %>% filter(marker != "Natural")

combine_data <- bind_rows(reduce, unreduced)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have dplyr 1.0.0 installed so I don't have `slice_sample`, but I assume you could do something similar with `slice_sample`

```
df <- data.frame(marker = rep(c('Natural', 'Other'), c(10, 10)),
                 x = runif(20))

df %>% 
  group_by(marker) %>% 
  sample_frac(if(first(marker) == 'Natural') .8 else 1)

# # A tibble: 18 x 2
# # Groups:   marker [2]
#    marker      x
#    <fct>   <dbl>
#  1 Natural 0.359
#  2 Natural 0.529
#  3 Natural 0.466
#  4 Natural 0.424
#  5 Natural 0.623
#  6 Natural 0.431
#  7 Natural 0.126
#  8 Natural 0.828
#  9 Other   0.545
# 10 Other   0.522
# 11 Other   0.826
# 12 Other   0.788
# 13 Other   0.580
# 14 Other   0.244
# 15 Other   0.633
# 16 Other   0.432
# 17 Other   0.920
# 18 Other   0.124
```